# Pyspark extracting four tuples from RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a rdd which contains five tuples as shown below

```
return [word_val+'&'+f_val+'&'+N_val+'&'+n_val+'&'+str(1)]
```

I want to map these values to compute result, I was expecting the mapping to work like:

```
reducer_3 = add_m.map(lambda word: (word[0],word[1],word[2],word[3],1)).reduceByKey(lambda word[0],1: word[0]+1)
```

And the reducer_3 should return an rdd containing:

```
word[0] & summation_of_1's & word[1] & word[2] & word[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to map into a pair tuple before the reduceByKey, e.g.:

```
reducer_3 = add_m.map(lambda word: ((word[0],word[1],word[2],word[3]),1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
```

This will return a set of 4-tuples and their counts. The original code you showed seemed to be missing the extra parens around the 4-tuple in the map step. 
Your question doesn't make it perfectly clear what you're trying to achieve, but hopefully the example above will help...

Comment: Im actually computing TF-IDF on a corpus. I want the map function to take  words from word[0] and perform: 
    reduceByKey(lambda word[0],1:  word[0]+1)

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of the input and output you want? To just count the instances of word[0], you would have to discard the rest of the tuple before the reduceByKey, e.g. `add_m.map(lambda word: (word[0],1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)`